# Laravel guzzle post request remote database error

Tags: laravel, post, guzzle

There is a Laravel 5.8 named `core` and Lumen 8 named `log` in my localhost. The `core` posts request to `log` and it must store the data into its database. They have separate database named `core_db` and `log_db`.

This is the `log` store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'metadata' => 'sometimes|json',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'action' => 'required|in:create,edit,delete,report',
        'entity_id' => 'required',
        'entity_type' => 'required',
        'key' => 'required|unique:logs,key',
        'encrypted_key' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return false;

    if($request->key != Crypt::decrypt($request->encrypted_key))
        return false;

    Log::create($request->all());
}
```

and `Log` model

```
class Log extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['entity_type', 'entity_id', 'user_id', 'metadata', 'action', 'key'];
    protected $table = 'logs';
}
```

and I am sure `.env` for `log` is set properly.

When I post to `log` via postman it works well without problem. But when I post to `log` via Guzzle from `core` as follows:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->post('http://localhost/log/public/store',
    [RequestOptions::JSON =>
        $data
    ]);
```

it reports error:

> Server error: `POST http://localhost/log/public/store` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!-- SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'core_db.logs' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggre (truncated...)

After debugging I findout that lines  `'key' => 'required|unique:logs,key'` and `Log::create()` are source of error, without them no error is reported.

I am try to insert or validate a data from `log` with its own database `log_db` and table `logs` not from `core`, why it reports  `core_db` has not `logs` table? Again I mention that from postman every thing is OK and post request from `core` made this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your postman request as well?

Comment: try with `json` instead of `RequestOptions::JSON`  and also return `json` response from your store method

Comment: @Pradeep the data sent from postman and `core` are the same. some strings and a json as metadata

Comment: @Pradeep Ok I will try your solution

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing the cache for both applications, this should solve your problem

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```